# Visual Studio Outlook Add-In Debug: No modules

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, debugging, outlook, debug-symbols

When I start debugging my Outlook (On-Send) Add-In, it initiates Outlook (Desktop) OK, but shows no modules. I know the App won't start until 'Send' but it won't hit any breakpoint - presumably for lack of modules - after 'Send'. Must be missing a setting, but I can't find what. Help appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to debug the `onSend` callback on the desktop except logging everything out. I'd suggest developing the feature in the browser where you can have access to browser's debugging tools and then testing it on the desktop edition of Outlook. I'd suggest leaving feedback on this on the [UserVoice](https://outlook.uservoice.com/) page.